# How to instruct browser to display a local page as if it was retrieved from the web

Tags: html, browser, web

I would like to open a html file, but in a way that the browser will act as if I browsed to that page from a specific site.That is, it should expand partial addresses with regards to this site, not my local file system.For example, `<img src=image/example.jpg>` should look for the image in http://examplesite.com/image/example.jpg and NOT in the current path.Any `POST` commands should be forwarded to the real server, etc.
I would like to do that, so that I will be able to download a simple webpage, edit it, and run it with the changes I made.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include a base-tag. This will effectively tell the browser where to start looking for references:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://examplesite.com/">
</head>
```

The base-tag needs the href-attribute, there can only be one and it has to be inside the head-tag

Check this link for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp